# chrome dev tools resource view little numbers

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

When I open the developer tools in chrome and go to the "Resources" tab, sometimes there are resources which have a red circle with a number to the right of the resource name.

What is that number?   You can see it at this site: http://www.realclearpolitics.com/?state=noad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some notes that depend from the color.

The red is for errors. Open the console to see the errors, then in the resource is trying to tell you where they found.

Then if you go to the resource with this red sign and move down you see the error line.

The yellow are messages.

The blue is for the search results.

The number is the times that this found.

Answer (score 1):

It shows the number of errors on the resource.

In the specified case, there is one error: an unmatched span close tag.